# VSTS - cannot release a build; The version provided for the Build Artifact source "blah" is invalid

Tags: azure-devops

It has been a while since I made a release from VSTS and I am having problems working out how to do it.
I already have a definition Sir-TestGeneric1. When I try to create a release for that definition, I am not getting any versions for the Artifacts. I try entering the BuildId but I still get the error message shown here;

[image]

When I look at the build definition I get this message;

[image]

Where are the permissions set for this?

Comment: Have you run a build recently?

Comment: yes. I wanted to release straight after the build.

Comment: @arame3333 Go to Build SIR-TEST to see whether there is valid completed builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that there was a name clash where SIR-TEST also had a XAML definition. Once I changed the name the artifacts then appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Build tab and check Build Definition `SIR-TEST` to see whether there is valid completed builds. If there is not valid builds under this Build Definition, you need to queue build first.

Comment: Yes there are valid builds for SIR-TEST

Comment: How about creating a new release definition? Are you able to select the artifacts?

Comment: I looked at the Release definition and posted what I found to the question above

Comment: Please go to `Security` on `Build` tab, and check whether the account of build agent has the `View build definition` and `View builds` permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/set-permissions?view=vsts